# How to insert code of image in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I had the picture with the following code.
But when I am trying to insert that code in beamer in Overleaf it does not compile at all.
I believe that some commands are missing.

Can anyone help me please? What should be added in preamble?

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.,0.,1.}

\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1.}

%\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}

%\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1.}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65][line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
%\clip(-3.52,-8.34) rectangle (26.66,8.32);


\fill[line width=2.pt,color=qqqqff,fill=qqqqff,fill opacity=0.0] (7.42,2.) -- (5.62,-0.6) -- (8.94,-0.68) -- cycle;
\fill[line width=2.pt,color=qqqqff,fill=qqqqff,fill opacity=0.0] (13.02,-0.68) -- (18.34,-0.78) -- (15.,1.6) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=1.pt,color=qqqqff] (7.42,2.)-- (5.62,-0.6);
\draw [line width=1.pt,color=qqqqff] (5.62,-0.6)-- (8.94,-0.68);
\draw [line width=1.pt,color=qqqqff] (8.94,-0.68)-- (7.42,2.);
\draw [line width=1.pt,,color=qqqqff] (7.58,4.18)-- (7.42,2.);
\draw [line width=1.pt,color=qqqqff] (13.02,-0.68)-- (18.34,-0.78);
\draw [line width=1.pt,color=qqqqff] (18.34,-0.78)-- (15.,1.6);
\draw [line width=1.pt,color=qqqqff] (15.,1.6)-- (13.02,-0.68);
\draw [line width=1.pt,,color=qqqqff] (15.,1.6)-- (16.5,4.2);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=ududff] (7.42,2.) circle (3.5pt);

\draw[color=qqqqff] (6.2,1) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$\alpha$}};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (8.3,1) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$\gamma$}};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (7.2,-1.2) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$\beta$}};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (7.2,3.2) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$\delta$}};

\draw[color=qqqqff] (13.5,0.7) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$r\alpha$}};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (15.5,-1.2) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$r\beta$}};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (17,0.7) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$r\gamma$}};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (15.4,3.2) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$r\delta$}};

\draw[color=black] (8.1,2) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$x_3$}};
\draw [fill=ududff] (5.62,-0.6) circle (3.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (5.2,-1) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$x_1$}};
\draw [fill=ududff] (8.94,-0.68) circle (3.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (9.5,-0.88) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$x_2$}};
\draw [fill=ududff] (7.58,4.18) circle (3.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (8.3,4.2) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$x_4$}};
\draw [fill=ududff] (13.02,-0.68) circle (3.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (12.6,-1) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$y_1$}};
\draw [fill=ududff] (18.34,-0.78) circle (3.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (19,-1) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$y_2$}};
\draw [fill=ududff] (15.,1.6) circle (3.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (14.4,1.7) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$y_3$}};
\draw [fill=ududff] (16.5,4.2) circle (3.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (17.1,4.2) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$y_4$}};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{trianglewithanedgeanditsdilatedcopy}
\caption{The graph $G$ and its dilated copy $rG$.}
\label{xxx}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example of the code you tried but could not compile. Include everything necessary to compile it theoretically, a class, the packages and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal code to make your code compilable is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
% Paste your code here

\end{document}
```

[image]

Moreover, about the showed code:

- The figure environment is an odd place for `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}`. It is better in the preamble where the library is available to all the document.
- Note that your code have a end of frame, without the begin of frame that I added above. To manage chunks of code, without pay attention to do not break any environments, is looking for troubles.
- The figure options (`[htbp]`) have no sense. Actually the `figure` environment is not a float in Beamer.
- The `\centering` is not needed at all. If you add just `\begin{figure} x \end{figure}` in a Beamer presentación, the "x" will be centered anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me! But I have a question: How should I assign a number to Figure? I mean I want it to be "Figure 1: The graph G and its dilated copy rG".

Comment: I think one needs to add `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]` to enumerate Figure. Thank you! I accept your answer!